# Ionic InAppPurchase2 (cordova-plugin-purchase) refund event does not trigger

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

while testing [inAppPurchase2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2) with their latest version as [cordova-plugin-purchase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-purchase) I notice that the refund event for consumables is never trigger (this in Android).

Did any of you have successfully trigger this event? I asked in [github](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/issues/991#issuecomment-582542622) and I got a comment about setting a `revoke` option that is not documented anywhere and no further answers for more than two weeks. I do not know how to proceed. I do the event listener as I do the other event states:

```
this.iap2.when(productId).refunded((product: IAPProduct) => {
  this.logger.log('refunded', product);
  alert('refunded');
});
```

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate what exactly do you mean by "refunds"? in both Apple/Google ecosystems such IAP functionality is typically not exposed. So interested to learn more about this use case and potentially help (I am using same plugin, but the refund policy is just "refund via Apple" etc)

Comment: Hi @SergeyRudenko, I mean how to get the info in my app that the user got a refund from the store. Using a tester account I can purchase a consumable, then I go to the correspond google account and request a refund there. I get an email with the confirmation of this refund but this is never triggered in the app. Neither in the same session or a posterior one.

Comment: Got it. But then you probably should know that  such data (of users refunds) is subject to a ton of snowflakes, unfortunately (there is no clean native SDK APIs for that), hence I am surprised this plugin can support any of that

Comment: I see, I do not know how other apps handle the refund of purchases for feature activation or similar.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, refund events are only ever fired via a web-hook you configure in the apple/google store.